# more than one top level TreeNode is possible?

Tags: java, jtree

first time use JTree. Just wondering is it possible to have more than one top level TreeNodes?
thanks

Comment: will have a customized treeModel because we need to update data at runtime based on data from database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can only be one root node. However you can set the JTree's [rootVisible property to false](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setRootVisible%28boolean%29), and then the first level children will be shown as top level nodes.

Comment: This way it looks like a forest, even though it isn't.  I have had to do this before.